# How to show that $E\left[X\mathbb{1}_{\{X \geq \lambda\}}\right] \geq \lambda P(X \geq \lambda)$ for $\lambda >0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have seen several books use the inequality without proof:

$$
E\left[X\mathbb{1}_{\{X \geq \lambda\}}\right] \geq \lambda P(X \geq \lambda)
$$

I am wondering if there is a way to prove this without resorting to hueristics?

Comment: This is Markov's inequality and the proof is very short: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov's_inequality

Comment: In short, if $X\ge\lambda$ in $\Omega$ then $\int_{\Omega} X\ge\int_{\Omega}\lambda=\lambda P(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov's_inequality). The random variable $(X-\lambda)\mathbb{1}_{X \geqslant \lambda}$ is nonnegative, so its expectation is nonnegative, i.e.
$$ 0 \leqslant E[(X-\lambda)\mathbb{1}_{X \geqslant \lambda}] = E[X\mathbb{1}_{X \geqslant \lambda}] - \lambda E[\mathbb{1}_{X \geqslant \lambda}], $$
and the latter term is just $P(X \geqslant \lambda)$.

Comment: If we were to apply Markov's Inequality, it states that $\mathbb{P}(Y \geq a) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(Y)}{a}$. In this case is our $Y$ equal to $X\mathbb{1}_{\{X \geq \lambda\}}$ or $X$?

Comment: Markov's inequality requires a positive random variable, so $Y = X \mathbb{1}_{\{X \geqslant \lambda\}}$. Then $P(Y \geqslant \lambda) = P(X \geqslant \lambda)$ since $Y$ is the same as $X$ on that set.